# Install many fonts at once

Tags: command-line, kde, fonts

I have about a hundred fonts that I need to install. Manually right clicking every font file and clicking install, then selecting "personal" vs "system" in a dialog that appears, and then closing it is tedious. Is there a command that will let me achieve the same effect in one shot? (I am using KDE.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just move all of the fonts you want to install to `~/.fonts` and then update the fontcache via:

```
fc-cache -rv
```

Note you might have to restart the application you want to use the fonts in for the changes to take effect.